# Changing NYS LLC mailing address

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, limited-liability-company

United State, NY state here.

I'd like to change my 1-man LLC's official mailing address with the state.  To my surprise, it looks like when I filed the original Articles of Organization over a year ago, I never had to specify the mailing address!  The only time NY state asked me to specify the mailing address was when they sent me an **LLC/LLP Request for Information** document a few days after I files the Articles on Division of Corporation's (*DoC's*) site; but this request came from the Department of Taxation and Finance, not the DoC.

Does this all sound right -- that the DoC wouldn't ask me to specify an address when I created the LLC?

Either way, to change our mailing address, do I go through DoC, Dept of Taxation/Finance, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to go through at least the DoC:

[DoC NY LLC Change Form](https://www.dos.ny.gov/forms/corporations/1359-f.pdf)

If you hold any other certificates/licenses you would have to contact those agencies (like a use-tax certificate or sales tax certificate). Your taxes shouldn't need notification unless you pay something other than your normal 1040/Schedule-C taxes (for example if you elected S-Corp status).

Comment: Thanks @Ron (+1) -- **yes** I should have mentioned, this is a 1-man LLC that has elected S-corp taxation. Is there a separate/2nd Dept Tax/Finance form that I would also need to fill out? Thanks again!

Comment: S-Corp is specifically federal (states usually tax LLC's as individuals), so if you filed your 2019 taxes with your new address, you're fine. If you haven't filled it out, you can submit an [IRS 8822](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc157). This is mostly for your EIN number and any correspondence.

Comment: Also BTW @Ron looks like there **is** a DTF form you need to fill out when changing your mailing address (DTF-96) but thanks again for the info here!